# Mysql Describe Query Row estimation

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I am trying to understand output of Describe statement.

Consider a query: `Describe Select 1 from TableName where attr1='Val1' and attr2='Val2'`

One of the output [Explained Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) is "rows" which estimates the number of rows that will be accessed on executing a select query with the same where Clause (attr1='Val1' and attr2='Val2'). 
How does this estimation done?

Thanks

Comment: The main reason I have used "Explain" on mysql and/or Oracle is to get a sense of how expensive a particular query is and to glean insight into how to optimize the query. The main recommendation I can make is to use Explain to determine if there is a condition in your where clause that matches against a value (column) that is NOT indexed. When a where clause condition has to check against every row in a table (full table scan) the query does extra work. If all conditions in the where clause are against indexed values the query will return more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` explains the order in which the tables (in a `JOIN`) will be touched and what index(es), if any, will be used.

`Rows` is an approximation that comes from statistics that are gathered in various ways, not of them very precise.  `ANALYZE TABLE` is a way to make the system recalculate the statistics.  If you have a `LIMIT`, then `Rows` is sometimes spectacularly wrong.

If you have `UNIQUE(attr1, attr2)` it might be smart enough to say `1` for `Rows`.  A table with N values and statistics that say A distinct values for attr1 and B distinct values for attr2 -- `Rows` might be something like A*B/N.  But, if `Val1` and `Val2` are common (or rare) values, this computation could be far off.

In some situations, the optimizer will make probes into the index to estimate how many rows are `Val1`, etc.  Since this is done *dynamically* (not statically, as with some other products), the `EXPLAIN` (and hence the query plan) may differ based on the values.  (I've seen as many as 6 different query plans for a `SELECT` that differed only in constants.)

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` (in 5.6) gives more details.  The "optimizer trace" gives even more detail.

`attr1='Val1' and attr2='Val2'` would like one of these, in order of preference:

- `INDEX(attr1, attr2, ...)` or `INDEX(attr2, attr1, ...)` if either exists; this is optimal; or
- `INDEX(attr1, ...)` or `INDEX(attr2, ...)`; it would pick based on selectivity, or
- A table scan, if none of the indexes above exist, or if the statistics say the indexes are not worth using.

If there is an `ORDER BY`, something else might happen.

If the index "covers" the query then `EXPLAIN` says `Using index`.  For example, `INDEX(attr3, attr1, attr2)` might be used, even though the entire index would have to be scanned -- `SELECT attr3 FROM t WHERE attr1='Val1' and attr2='Val2'`.

If you would like to discuss a particular query, present it.  *All* parts of a query *may* impact what the `EXPLAIN` says.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) are some basic rules on how to build optimal indexes.